# Getting multi count from two table and save it in one variable in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two tables and I need to get the count of these tables for a condition?

**table 1:** "tbl_comment" **table 2:** "tbl_group_comment"
both have some common columns which are login_id of the user,

**this is the query:**

```php
$param="(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_comment as t2 WHERE login_id=1) as commentCount, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_group_comment as t3 WHERE login_id=1) as commentCount";
$table="`tbl_comment` t2 join `tbl_group_comment`";
$save['value']=$this->Common_model->common_join($param,$table);
```

this one is not working but if I am changing the second `commentCount` and keep it as `commentCount1` it will give me the value of each table, I want to get the sum of both counts?

is there any specific clause for this matter?

Comment: Can you show your model file?

Comment: @vivek_23 I updated the code, can you check it now !?

Comment: I think you need to make the query in the common join method rather than passing query as a parameter!

Comment: Also, you can make use of `union` to get them as separate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(comment_count + group_count) from 
((SELECT COUNT(*) as comment_count FROM tbl_comment WHERE login_id=1) A,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as group_count FROM tbl_group_comment WHERE login_id=1)B
);
```

Comment: but what is A and B here?

Comment: alias name for sub queries.

Comment: In Mysql, alias name should be there for derived tables, otherwise it will give an Error: Every derived table must have its own alias